# sails: disable `blueprints actions` in production, since it creates a huge security footprint?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Getting acquinted with [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/#!) for Node.

One thing I need to get used to is the 'automagic' way in which routes for controller-methods are set-up using `blueprints`.

For example, from the docs, if `actions`-blueprints are enabled (**which they are by default**) GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE routes will be generated for every one of a controller's actions.

E.g from the docs, when you've got controlled-method `EmailController.send` the following routes are created:

```
     * `EmailController.send`
     * :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     * `GET     /email/send/:id?`
     * `POST    /email/send/:id?`
     * `PUT     /email/send/:id?`
     * `DELETE  /email/send/:id?`
```

The docs specifically state: `actions` are enabled by default, and are OK for production-- however, you must take great care **not to inadvertently expose unsafe controller logic to GET requests**.

Normally I would write a controller-method for ONE specific HTTP Verb (e.g.: POST). That's clearly **not** compatible with this automagic wiring, since these methods would be exposed on GETs (and PUTs and DELETEs) as well, which would leave a huge security footprint imho.

So: what's the practical use of enabling these `actions`? To me, it seems like a huge security risk. On the other hand, I can (theoretically) imagine writing **all** controller methods with conditional logic to discriminate between HTTP VERBS , but for most controller methods this just doesn't make sense.

So help me out: What's the advantage of working with these `actions` which Sails seems to try to nudge me towards?  Or is it just a way to get going quickly, but really not meant for production?

Thanks for wrapping my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action Blueprints automatically create routes to all the available controller methods. I personally turn them off, and do my routing manually.

Restful blueprints automatically generate the controller methods themselves. Which would then have routes to them created by the Action Blueprints. I believe these are the rest defaults....

```
 * GET      /boat/:id?      -> BoatController.find
 * POST     /boat           -> BoatController.create
 * PUT      /boat/:id       -> BoatController.update
 * DELETE   /boat/:id       -> BoatController.destroy
```

Comment: I rather like the REST blueprints, and figure I'm going to enable them in production (with the correct policies). What I dislike are the Action Blueprints. I asked because it may be a personal taste I dislike them, so I want to know the reasoning behind ever wanting to enable them in prod.

Comment: You can use the rest blueprints with action blueprints disabled. You just have to make the routes by hand.

Comment: I personally don't use the blueprints because I needed more control over my controller methods.

Comment: Did you know how add policies to blueprints restful methods ?? I did find how do this