# How do I implement row-level permissions using blueprint routes in SailsJS 1.x?

Tags: sails.js

I'm using Sails version 1.2.3 to build rest APIs. Our application requires row-level permissions for some entities. For example, for the same API, certain users/roles the rest API should return a subset of the data. For elevated users the rest API should return the full set of data.

Instead of build custom routes/actions for our application, I'd like to use sails blueprint routes, and apply the necessary row-level permissions to the blueprint routes.

I've tried reviewing the sails-auth and sails-permissions npm packages, but they don't work for sails 1.x.

Is there a way to do this in the current version of SailsJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your app seems not a tutorial-stage one, you should consider disabling blueprints at all, its a security risk. Then you can handle that logic for roles/data given within your controllers or services.

[sails: disable `blueprints actions` in production, since it creates a huge security footprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156944/sails-disable-blueprints-actions-in-production-since-it-creates-a-huge-secur)

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question - If I disable the blueprint routes and switch to custom controllers/actions, what's the best way to still utilize the query options provided in the blueprint routes.

For example, in the blueprint route I can do something like this: <api-endpoint>/populates=false,&elect=name,abbreviation&where=...

Creating generic routes with dynamic query options allows my front end team to be more productive, and allows our back-end apis to be less complex. Thanks again!

Comment: In this case probably the best today's solution is GraphQL. It does that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mansim. But still, if you want to do this you must override the find and findOne controllers as per requirement.

Steps should be like as follows:

1. Create a policy that will set a permission flag in the 'req' object.
2. Read flag from 'req' in the findOne/find method.
3. Use _.omit(or any javascript method) to remove the details which you don't want to send.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Follow up question, with the _.omit approach, does the database return all data to sails, then sails filters out the data it shouldn't pass to the front end app?

Comment: @sbenner in controller you'll get data, the controller will return JSON as a response after filtering out.